# Multi-variate correlation analysis

Tags: correlation

I have a several variables. I have a set of experiments which indicate whether each of these variables has a positive signal in the experiments or not. I need to identify what subset of the variables which is mostly correlated with each other in the subset. I know we can do correlation analysis to test the relationship between two variables. How to do this to test the relationship of multiple variables together, at once?

Comment: What do you mean by "the relationship of multiple variables together"?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read this [Multiple Correlation](http://www.real-statistics.com/correlation/multiple-correlation/). There are useful formulas, proofs and examples (but only in Excel). I think, that's a good post to understand multiple correlation.